# Laravel - Catch exception in custom handler

Tags: laravel, exception, render, handler, laravel-5.5

I'm using Laravel 5.5 and I want to handle my custom exceptions from custom handlers, not from `app\Exceptions\Handler.php`. Now, I catch an exception if some field it's empty in the form submitted by the user. It's perfectly working like this:

1. **ProfileController.php**:

   ```
   public function update(Request $request, $id){
       $this->guzzleService->put(
           $request,
           ApiEndPoints::UPDATE_PROFILE . $id,
           true
       );

       return back()->with('SavedCorrectly', 'Changes saved correctly');
   }
   ```
2. **app\Exceptions\Handler.php**

   ```
   public function render($request, Exception $exception)
   {
       if($exception instanceof ClientException && $exception->getCode() == 422)
           return back()->withErrors(
               json_decode((string) $exception->getResponse()->getBody(), TRUE)["errors"]
           );

       return parent::render($request, $exception);
   }
   ```

The problem is that I want to refactor that, so that it remains like this:

1. **ProfileController.php**

   ```
   public function update(Request $request, $id){
       try {
           $this->guzzleService->put(
               $request,
               ApiEndPoints::UPDATE_PROFILE . $id,
               true
           );

           return back()->with('SavedCorrectly', 'Cambios guardados correctamente');
       } catch(ClientException $exception) {
           if ($exception->getCode() == 500) throw new InternalServerErrorException;
           if ($exception->getCode() == 422) throw new UnprocessableEntityException;
       }
   }
   ```
2. **app\Exceptions\HttpExceptions\UnprocessableEntityException.php**

   ```
   <?php

   namespace App\Exceptions\HttpExceptions;

   use GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException;

   class UnprocessableEntityException extends \Exception
   {
       public function render($request, ClientException $exception)
       {
           return back()->withErrors(
               json_decode((string) $exception->getResponse()->getBody(), TRUE)["errors"]
           );
       }
   }
   ```

But I'm receiving this error:

> Type error: Argument 2 passed to
>   App\Exceptions\HttpExceptions\UnprocessableEntityException::render()
>   must be an instance of GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException, none
>   given, called in
>   ... \vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler.php
>   on line 169

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is because you are passing a new exception

```
public function update(Request $request, $id){
    try {
        $this->guzzleService->put(
            $request,
            ApiEndPoints::UPDATE_PROFILE . $id,
            true
        );

        return back()->with('SavedCorrectly', 'Cambios guardados correctamente');
    } catch(ClientException $exception) {
        if ($exception->getCode() == 500) throw new InternalServerErrorException((string) $exception->getResponse()->getBody());
        if ($exception->getCode() == 422) throw new UnprocessableEntityException((string) $exception->getResponse()->getBody());
    }
}
```

and

```
<?php

namespace App\Exceptions\HttpExceptions;

use GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException;

class UnprocessableEntityException extends \Exception
{
    public function render($request)
    {
        return back()->withErrors(
            json_decode((string) $this->message, TRUE)["errors"]
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked. I suspected the reason but I didn't know how to do it.